# Error when trying to show validation error messages in Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, validation

Attaching my codesandbox link below for reference
https://codesandbox.io/s/misty-flower-qzmzo?file=/src/App.vue

Can anyone please help me on, How to add a listener to validate on the initial input.

```html
 <input
          type="text"
          class="form-control"
          placeholder="First Name"
          value=""
          v-model="user.name"
        />
        <div
          v-if="this.submitted && !$v.user.name.required"
          class="invalid-feedback left"
        >
          Enter Username
        </div>

<input
          type="text"
          class="form-control"
          placeholder="Enter your company email ID"
          value=""
          v-model="user.email"
          autocomplete="off"
        />
        <div
          v-if="this.submitted && $v.user.email.$error"
          class="invalid-feedback left"
        >
          <span v-if="!$v.user.email.required">Email is required</span>
          <span v-if="user.email && !$v.user.email.email"
            >Enter valid email address</span
          >
          <span
            v-if="user.email && $v.user.email.email && !$v.user.email.maxLength"
            >Email is allowed only 30 characters</span
          >
        </div>
```

I am working on the form validations error messages, but the issue with that is, Initially when the form is loaded, error validations are displaying like "this field is required"

But i want those validation error messages to be shown, when user enter any characters in input field and then if he delete that then the validations should show.

Attaching my codesandbox link below for reference
https://codesandbox.io/s/misty-flower-qzmzo?file=/src/App.vue

Comment: Adding a listener is a new question and you really aught to make a new post about that instead of redirecting the current question to this new thing.

Also you should really try to do this yourself and then post a question if you are having issues and give the code you have tried. Many people (including myself) are happy to help, but are not as willing to just code answers for people. You need to put time and effort into figuring things out as well!

Answer (score -1):

In your `created()` function, these two lines are causing form validation to trigger. What is the purpose of these two lines of code?

```js
created() {
   this.submitted = true;
   return this.$v.$touch();
},
```

It seems odd you are setting the submitted flag to true on load.

Also, if you are wanting to focus an input field, add the [`autofocus`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_autofocus.asp) attribute.

Removing both of these lines solves your issue and stops form validation. Removing just `this.$v.$touch()` will cause only the first input to validate.

EDIT: As requested here is an updated code example. You had a few errors in your validation logic and were missing the trigger for validation on your form submit.

https://codesandbox.io/s/nameless-wildflower-jqt8e

Here is more info on validation:

https://webomnizz.com/form-handling-and-validation-with-vuejs/

Comment: I have removed  those lines of code, but still it's showing same.

Comment: If possible can you  please edit and provide the codesandbox link

Comment: @santoshchandu I see you removed those lines of code, and just the first input field is validating - can you confirm?

Comment: @santoshchandu Updated. If you want to validation before you press submit, you should add a listener to the lose focus event and validate the field that focus was left on.

Comment: Sorry, I checked your code https://codesandbox.io/s/nameless-wildflower-jqt8e?file=/src/App.vue. Still it is the same no changes are reflecting.

Comment: But I want those validation error messages to be shown, when user enter any characters in input field and then if he remove those characters  then the validations should show.(like this field is required). But above it's reflecting during onclick of register

Comment: @santoshchandu I can take a look at it in a few, but look at my previous comment. You need to add a listener to validate on the initial input.

Comment: ,Ok i will check the listener to validate input. Meanwhile can you please edit the codesandbox with listener to validate input.

It will be very helpfull to me

Comment: @santoshchandu I am pretty busy, but if you could take a look at the listeners and give it a go, I can see what you get and help if needed.